# Evaluating the alternating series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find such alternating series sum?

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}
\end{equation}

Comment: **Hint :**
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}=\underbrace{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(-\frac13\right)^{n-1}}_{\color{blue}{\text{infinite GP }\Rightarrow\dfrac{a}{1-r}}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac13}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left(-\frac13\right)^{n-1}$$ which is an infinite Geometric Series with

the first term $\displaystyle\left(-\frac13\right)^{0-1}=3$

and common ratio $\displaystyle r=\left(-\frac13\right)^{-1}$ with $|r|<1$

Do you know the formula of the sum?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry - I have found my mistake - it starts from 1, not zero, so it's 1 -1/3 + 1/9 - 1/27 + ... and so on.

Comment: So it must be convergent series.

Comment: @LeoMatyushkin, Definitely. Hope you understand the start index does not matter

Comment: @LeoMatyushkin, See also : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about geometric series, when thought about this problem. But now I see this is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If $\left|r\right|<1$ then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{n}=\left(1-r\right)^{-1}$$
Apply that here for $r=-\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}
\end{equation}

Start submitting n in the above equation and you will get terms $(T_n)$ like below

$T_1=1$

$T_2=\large \frac{-1}{3}$

$T_3=\large \frac{1}{3^2}$

$T_4=\large \frac{-1}{3^3}$

So the sum $S=T_1+T_2+T_3+T_4+...$

The common ratio $r=\large \frac {-1}{3}$ and $a=1$

Then the sum is $S=\large {\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}}}$

Or, $S=0.75$

Comment: This is confusing because $T_n$ typically denotes the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number.

Comment: @dleggas Really? Because $T=F$?

Comment: @Did I meant Triangle number. That was just a malfunction on my part...

Comment: @dleggas Thus people should be forbidden to use capital T for *anything else*? This does not seem very reasonable, does it?

Comment: @Did I think you are a bit too excited about my original comment. I did not say that the answer was incorrect or that it was false to use "T," I said it was confusing, in my opinion, at first glance. So quit your tirade of loaded questions. Logical fallacies are annoying aren't they?

Comment: @dleggas There is no logical fallacy at work here. (Or is it a "tirade" to mention this fact?)